# Guzzle: mocking external calls in functional tests?

Tags: mocking, phpunit, symfony, guzzle

I am currently working on a Symfony3 project using Guzzle. My project calls several externals API, and I would like to mock these requests in my functional tests.

Looking at [Guzzle documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/testing.html), it seems the way to follow is to use both mock handler and history middleware. Yet, I am surprised there is no built-in solution for this common task (or at least, I didn't find it).

What I would expect is to write my tests with something like:

```
$mockedClient = new MockedClient([
    ['GET', '/foo', 200, 'Hello world!'],
    ['GET', '/bar', 200, 'Hello another world!'],
]);

$mockedClient->verify();
```

Which solution are you using ? :)

Comment: Yes, I have used the method described in the doc in some functional test in the past. When you configure the expected response, you could pass it as dependency to the service under test (or override the guzzle defined in the container), and then use as usually. let me know if you need further info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed quite tricky as there is no proper Symfony Guzzle wrapper

Here is how I use Guzzle mocking feature in its latest version (it has changed in the latest Guzzle version, it used to be simpler!!):

First of all, I design my service to have the Guzzle client injected (through a second service that extends GuzzleHttp\Client):

```
my_guzzleclient:
   class: ...MyGuzzleClient
my_service:
   class: ...MyService
   arguments: ['@my_guzzleclient']
```

Then, in my test, I create a mock handler:

```
$mock = new MockHandler([
    new Response(200, array(), array())
]);
```

And finally, I override my custom guzzle client (my_guzzleclient) with a new one that takes my mock handler into account

```
$client->getContainer()->set('my_guzzleclient', new MyGuzzleClient($mock));
```

Here is the code of MyGuzzleClient

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as BaseClient

class MyGuzzleClient extends BaseClient
{
    /**
     * MyGuzzleClient  constructor.
     * @param bool|MockHandler $handler
     */
    public function __construct($handler = false)
    {
        $options = array();

        if ($handler !== false) {
            $options['handler'] = $handler;
        }

        parent::__construct($options);
    }
```

Good luck,
Arnaud

Answer (score 1):

Also, take a look at [PHPUnit HTTP mock](https://github.com/InterNations/http-mock) project. It suits perfectly for real acceptance tests, where you want to test your app almoust untouched (without code modification, just small config changes maybe). Internally it's possible by creating a small standalone HTTP server and mock/check all requests inside it.

Comment: I saw this tool, yet it won't fulfill my need. We already have some E2E tests to figure out the global optimistic behavior. Yet, I wanted to mock requests in order to test some edge cases. :)

Comment: OK! But have you seen the example here: https://github.com/InterNations/http-mock/blob/master/doc/start.md ?

You can mock almost all parameters of the remote server, like the response status code, response body or even response generation time. Don't know about your edge cases, but mine I test with this tool :)